# Geocode area/neigborhood into polygon vertices

Tags: polygon, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api, vertices

I have been successfully using the Google Maps API using the R package *ggmap* to find location coordinates for e.g. addresses or city names.

However, Google Maps now shows areas as well, indicating their extent with a transparent red polygon, e.g. when searching for "South Extension I, New Delhi", it shows the extent of this area/neigborhood (figure below).

[image: Maps Geocode Neighborhood example]

The Google Maps API only seems to return the coordinates of the geometric center, and the viewport (rectangular) boundary coordinates (after zooming to the area extent): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

How can I obtain the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon which indicates the area/neighborhood?